# Expiration for Trello OAuth tokens

Tags: oauth, trello

Our service has a Trello integration, and we use OAuth to authenticate and authorize users. However, we're seeing all of our calls to Trello fail until the service reauthenticates the user. This started with a call to https://api.trello.com/1/lists to post a card, which received a 401 response. Getting a new token (by effectively reauthenticating) solved the problem, so it's not a permissions issue.

This problem initially sounded like a token expiration issue (since `expiration=never` is evidently supported), but it hasn't happened in the past and we've been using Trello's API for well over a year. Does anyone happen to know Trello's default OAuth token expiration and whether this has changed recently?

Thanks!

Comment: I interested in too. Please answer someone how to deal with 401 error properly. I mean Trello ClientJS library https://developers.trello.com/clientjs

Answer (score 0):

If an expiration is not provided in the request, the default value for the OAuth1.0 flow is `30days`.

`401`s can also be caused by a user revoking a Trello token from their accounts page: https://trello.com/my/account.

Additionally, you can check the expiration date of a token via the [`1/tokens` route](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#tokenstoken): https://trello.com/1/tokens/{tokenValue}?key={TrelloAPIKey}&token={tokenValue}.

An example response to that route looks like this:

`{
  "id": "a58541ff795dc3d9a124374b",
  "identifier": "My Trello Token",
  "idMember": "5859bd30f6582fbf01f4a8fc",
  "dateCreated": "2016-12-16T16:45:06.810Z",
  "dateExpires": null,
  "permissions": [
    {
      "idModel": "69bdfbf01f58582530f4a8fc",
      "modelType": "Member",
      "read": true,
      "write": true
    },
    {
      "idModel": "*",
      "modelType": "Board",
      "read": true,
      "write": true
    },
    {
      "idModel": "*",
      "modelType": "Organization",
      "read": true,
      "write": true
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

A Trello access token by default never expires. You can check this here:

```
https://trello.com/{username}/account
```

Under the 'Applications' section, you will find details of the API tokens associated with your account.